# Force external component to re-render with new props

Tags: react-native

I am trying to set up e-mail sign-up. I have a screen with a `TextInput`, which I want to reuse. I have an `EmailConnector` from which I navigate to the `TextInputScreen`. This `TextInputScreen` containt a `TextInputComponent`. Here, the user enters his email. If the email is invalid, I throw an error and try to update the error message in my `TextInputScreen`.

The problem that I am facing right now is that the error message from my `TextInputComponent` is not updated when an error is thrown.

The flow is this:

1. The user taps on "Sign-up with email" in a separate screen -> `openEmailScreen` is called
2. The user inputs an email and taps on the keyboard "Done" button -> `inputReceived` is called
3. If the email is invalid -> an error is thrown in `inputReceived` and the error message is displayed in `TextInputViewComponent`

Refreshing the errror message in step #3 is NOT working at the moment and I can't figure out how to get it working.

This is my EmailConnector:

```
export default class EmailConnector {
    static keyboardTypes = {
        email: 'email-address',
        default: 'default',
    };

    static openEmailScreen = async navigation => {
        navigation.navigate('TextInputScreen', {
            placeholder: strings.onboarding.email_flow.email_placeholder,
            keyboardType: this.keyboardTypes.email,
            onKeyboardPressed: () => this.inputReceived(),
            errorMessage: 'placeholder message',
        })
    }
    //method called when the "Done" button from the keyboard is pressed
    static inputReceived = () => {
        try {
            const email = new SignUpUserBuilder().setEmail('testexample.com').build();//used to validate the email
        }
        catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
            ****//HERE I need to figure out a way to change props.errorMessage and force TextInputViewComponent to rerender****
            <TextInputViewComponent errorMessage = 'Invalid email'/>;
            const viewComponent = new TextInputViewComponent();
            viewComponent.forceUpdate();
        }
    } 
}
```

This is my TextInputScreen:

```
class TextInputScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.rootView}>
                <TextInputViewComponent 
                    placeholder={this.props.route.params.placeholder}
                    keyboardType={this.props.route.params.keyboardType}
                    onKeyboardPressed={this.props.route.params.onKeyboardPressed}
                    errorMessage={this.props.route.params.errorMessage}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default TextInputScreen;
```

And this is my TextInputViewComponent:

```
class TextInputViewComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            shouldRefreshComponent: false
        }
    }

    refreshComponent = () => {
        this.setState({
            shouldRefreshComponent: true
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View> 
                <TextInput 
                    placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                    placeholderTextColor={colors.placeholder}
                    keyboardType={this.props.keyboardType}
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    onSubmitEditing= {() => this.props.onKeyboardPressed()}
                />
                <Text 
                style={{fontSize: 18, color: colors.white}}
                ref={Text => { this._textError = Text}}>
                    {this.props.errorMessage}
                    </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default TextInputViewComponent;
```

From the `inputReceived` method, I have tried calling `forceUpdate` and `setState` for the `TextInputViewComponent`, but in both cases I get the message: `"Can't call forceUpdate/setState on a component that is not yet mounted"`

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In general terms if I want a parent component to mutate it's data or update when a child component changes I pass the child a function to its props.

For example

```js
class Parent {
  state = {
    value: 1
  }
  updateValue() {
    this.setState({value: 2})
  }
  render() (
    <Child 
      updateValue={this.updateValue}
    />
  )
```

That way I can call the function inside the child to update the parent's state.

```js
class Child {
 updateParent() {
   this.props.updateValue()
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but my problem is different. My problem is that I can NOT update a component from a JavaScript class. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean that you're trying to have the Parent trigger the Child's update?

Comment: I was trying to trigger an update on `TextInputViewComponent` from `EmailConnector`. I ended up using a callback. Thanks for the answer! :)

Comment: The answer I gave you is the same as using a callback. Essentially passing a function as an argument to another function that triggers it is a callback. When you pass a function into a component's props you're passing it as an argument. JSX and react just sugar coat the actual implementation.

Comment: The best way to think of react components is as functions. If a component is a function then its props are the function's arguments. Props are just function arguments that you're not allowed to mutate.